# Selective reinforcement of some places in my part

Tags: prusa-i3, slic3r

I have a part that experiences larger than average forces in some of its protrusions. It would make sense to reinforce walls, and in particular strengthen infill in those areas. But to save material and printing time, I would like to use thinner walls etc for the rest of the part.

Are there any tricks for how to do this, other than printing two parts with different parameters and joining them somehow?

This is Prusa i3 with slic3r.

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE! There's two things I can think of off the top of my head: 1) use a stronger material (such as ABS instead of PLA) to print your part; 2) use fillet radii where you can which will help reduce/eliminate stress risers (areas where the part can break easier). I'm sure there's ways to make certain areas more resilient, but I personally don't have an answer for you there :o)

Comment: There is an answer that does exactly what you want, e.g. have [multiple infill percentages](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/6523); I'm pretty sure you can change wall count as well. I can't test it at the moment. Note that this is advanced slicing!