# Adaptive infill density in small region

Tags: ultimaker-cura, infill, print-strength

I'm using Ultimaker Cura to slice my 3D models, and I often have a problem with object with dimensions over multiple orders of magnitudes.

Basically, if I set an Infill of 20 %, the infill is calculated for the entire region, regardless of whether for each z-stack, the region is actually a closed one, or multiple separated ones.

As a result, the fragility is increased in those tiny regions that have no filling, because overall, the infill percentage is respected, but out of unfortunate yet inevitable  statistics, the parts with no infill ended up colocalizing with the regions that needed infill the most.

[image]

As you can see in this famous Llamacorn, some closed regions have no infill at all (right side), and the left arrow shows how the infill is calculated based on the entire structure rather than the local one.

Any adaptive option hidden somewhere?

Do I need to tweak the model directly?

Comment: Cura has a gradual infill option. You can find it under Infill. However, this assumes you only want to vary your infill based on height.

Comment: Cura Maker is not a distribution I know. What is the version number or is this a derivative?

Comment: Sorry I meant Ultimaker Cura

Comment: Please look into [this](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/6522/) question, there is no automatic infill based on volume. Good idea though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the right region does have a calculated infill; it just happens to be at the edge of the inner wall.

[image: Zoomed rendering of a model with a thin black line to show infill line]

I have drawn a thin black line along the infill lines for this layer and you can see that there is a small infill line.

Cura has a feature called "Support Blocker" that allows you to change the settings for certain areas of your model. You could make those particular areas have an infill of 100 % if you like.

Chuck Hellebuyck has a video on his YouTube channel that explains how to set this up. It's not that difficult and will take some time to get the area just the way you want it. The information for the "Support Blocker" starts at timestamp 2:01.

Another idea is to try rotating the model on the build plate to "force" an infill line to be generated where you need it. The only problem with this is that you may spend more time trying to get all the areas filled the way you want them.

Comment: That's exactly the point of my question. I am wondering if there is any way to automate the infill calculation so that the pattern is not calculated on the overall shape, but locally, where infill is really needed. If you compute the % coverage of the small thin line you highlighted, it is clearly not the original 15 or 20%, locally speaking. I added extra walls in this screenshot, but I don't like this fake workaround as it does not solve any "void space" issue.

Comment: + if I rotate it, I may be lucky for this leg, but maybe not for the 3 other legs and the neck. Rotating is just playing with luck rather that having a rational solution.

Comment: @Myoch I just remember about the "Support Blocker" feature in Cura and added the information above.

Comment: There is a separate [question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/6522/) on the different infill percentage, as far as I know there is no automatic option that calculates infill percentage based on enclosed volume by the perimeter.