# Print Object Without Top Layer But With Intermediate Layers

Tags: slicing, openscad, prusaslicer

I'm using PrusaSlicer with OpenSCAD.  I want to print a solid object with a notch in it, without top layers, but with infill and solid walls for the notch, like this...

[image: Screenshot of the preview of a 3D model in PrusaSlicer]

I can set the number of top layers to zero (**Print Settings** > **Layers and perimeters** > **Solid Layers** > **Top** = 0), which gets rid of the top layers as desired, but it also removes the base from the notch, like this...

[image: Screenshot of the preview of a 3D model in PrusaSlicer with no Top Layers]

Is there any way to do what I want without awful shenanigans in OpenSCAD or editing G-code?

Comment: Please indicate (by [edit]) if the geometry should be fully printed, or if you can live with a shorter (height) object. Also [edit] your question which printer you have.

Answer (score 3):

I just confirmed it works flawlessly in PrusaSlicer as it did in Slic3r, the software from which PrusaSlicer is forked. Just use the solution provided in "[Different infill in the same part](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6522/different-infill-in-the-same-part/6523#6523)", but now do not change infill options but the layer options.

First load the cube with notch, and then load/insert a modifier to get something like the following (grey is the box with notch, green cube is the modifier):

[image]

Now change the options (click on modifier and left-click to select `Layers and Perimeters` option item) of the modifier (select zero top and bottom layers):
[image]

The sliced solution will look like what you request:
[image]

Note that this solution will give you an object that is exactly the height of the designed cube, it just doesn't have a top surface, but infill and walls to the top.

Answer (score 0):

I would just pause at the second to last layer, remove the print and cancel it.

With Cura you can do this easily in the slicer. Or just manually do it.

I have never used Prusaslicer but all slicers must have this. For more information, see the Prusa documentation ["Insert pause or custom G-code at layer"](https://help.prusa3d.com/article/insert-pause-or-custom-g-code-at-layer_120490).

Comment: The print will be too short, it will be missing the last layers. At least advise to alter the design by extending the top part by the thickness of the top layers.

Comment: @0scar how do you work that out? The OP specifically says they don't want the top layer. This is how I do it when I want the infill texture on top, and it works fine.

Comment: Simple, if you have 5 top layers at 0.2 mm per layer, your object is too short, by 1 mm. I assume the size is important, if not your answer is very valid, I've left a comment for the OP. Note that the OP specifies that the notch needs top layers, those settings apply for the top surface as well, so if you stop the print before the printing of the top layers, it is too short.. Please explain better if this is not what is meant in your answer.

Comment: @Oscar you're assuming that 1mm is important, and assuming the OP wouldn't use common sense? Never mind, feel free to downvote