# Cura: Ensure wall thickness on curves

Tags: ultimaker-cura, slicing

Is it possible to tell Cura that the wall thickness should be equal not only horizontal but also on a vertical point of view?

Example:
This is how it would look on a curve when I set wall thickness to 4:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**No**, the definition of wall thickness is in horizontal direction, not vertical or perpendicular. The hint info of the "Wall Thickness" option describes this.

[image]

However, if you have very curved surfaces that require more walls, but you don't want to have all these walls in the whole print is use a technique described in question [Different infill in the same part](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6522/different-infill-in-the-same-part). [This answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/6523/) describes the use of a different infill percentage, but you can also change the amount of walls; so in these curved regions, you could locally increase the amount of walls, e.g.:

[image]