# Define PrusaSlicer infill modifiers in STL/3MF?

Tags: 3d-design, stl, infill, prusaslicer, cad

I use a procedural 3D animation package (SideFX Houdini) for my 3D object design.  After exporting my design to STL then importing to PrusaSlicer, I manually place modifier objects to adjust the infill percent on certain areas.  I'd like the ability to procedurally designate the infill percentage in certain areas in my design.

Is there a way to flag an object in STL/3MF/Other file format so it's interpreted as an infill adjustment modifier in PrusaSlicer?

Comment: This question is closely related to [this question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6522/), PrusaSlicer is a derivative of Slic3r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So worked out you can't directly do this with metadata, however you can add modifiers to objects in PrusaSlicer, and you can use external STLs as the geometry for the modifier.  Then you can add an infill property to the modifier and set different parameters there.

[image]